# `\` inside a string does not escape anything

Tags: json, ruby, string

The character `\` is used to escape some characters in a string. I need a string that includes `\` like this:

```
str = "Lucas Andrade \"My name\""
```

When I print `str`, I should see this:

```
print str
# >> Lucas Andrade \"My name\"
```

I will embed this string directly inside a json param to send an API request using HTTParty like this example:

```
params {
  "name": "Lucas",
  "json": {
    "address": "some",
    "street": "example",
    "string": "the custom \"string\""
  }
}
```

I think HTTParty does not format this string automatically.

Comment: _"``\`` inside a string does not escape anything"_ – not true, it escapes the `"` which would otherwise end the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not very fluent in Ruby, but this is commonly done with `"\\"`, resulting in `"\"`

So, `"Lucas Andrade \\\"My name\\\""` should result in what you're looking for, an escaped `\` and an escaped `"`

Answer (score 3):

When you need to send the string as JSON to an API, why don't you use `JSON.generate` to escape the string as needed?

```
JSON.generate("Lucas Andrade \"My name\"")
```

Comment: The OP should probably generate the whole JSON structure out of a Ruby hash.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it in single quote marks.

```
str = 'Lucas Andrade "My name"'
=> "Lucas Andrade \"My name\""
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. He needs the output to include the backslash character and the output of `puts 'Lucas Andrade "My name"'` does not include a backslash.

Comment: There's a bit of confusion from OP: ` So when I print my str I should see this: "Lucas Andrade \"My name\""` which my answer does. But OP also says they want the backslash therein.

Comment: In ruby `puts` and `print` are different, that's why I said `print`. In your answer the \ are just represented by ruby output syntax, the are not part of the string.

Comment: `puts` is like `print` with newline (if missing).